# How to access Sharepoint REST api in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

I'm new to working with sharepoint. When i tried to call share point API url from ajax call in JavaScript. But, it's continuously failing and throws the error. I can say, that is CORS error. So, i've made changes in web.config like below.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept,X- FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED,crossDomain,credentials " />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

and ajax call as below

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var items = data.d;
                console.log("Login Name: " + items.LoginName);
                console.log("Email: " + items.Email);
                console.log("ID: " + items.Id);
                console.log("Title: " + items.Title);
            },
            error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqxr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Please help me regarding this. I'm trying since 2 days.

> Update:

This error I'm getting.

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the PowerShell script below to add the web.config modifications:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0

$localFarm = Get-SPFarm

$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp:12001"

# Remove old web.config modifications of MyAuthenticationProvider
$oldMods = @();
$webapp.WebConfigModifications | ? { $_.Owner -eq "CrossSiteScripting" } | % { 
    $oldMods = $oldMods + $_
}

$oldMods | % { 
    $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($_) 
}

# update the Web Application and apply all existing web.config modifications - this executes the "remove" actions from above
$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}

# New web.config modifications for MyAuthenticationProvider
$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin'][@value='http://localhost:31699']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
#0 = for the enum value "SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value='http://localhost:31699' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Method'][@value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Method' value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Headers'][@value='Content-Type,Authorization']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Headers' value='Content-Type,Authorization' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'][@value='true']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' value='true' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Then use the REST API in jQuery Ajax like below.

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d;
        console.log("Login Name: " + items.LoginName);
        console.log("Email: " + items.Email);
        console.log("ID: " + items.Id);
        console.log("Title: " + items.Title);
    },
    error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Reference: [Cross Site Scripting with SharePoint 2013 REST calls](https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, actually i'm getting data form sharepoint in XML format not JSON. Then what are the modifications do i need to change in JavaScript?

Comment: Modify the headers : headers: { "Accept": "application/atom+xml" },